# Android RecyclerView Single Click selects multiple rows

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hello I am developing an app which uses recyclerview to show items to select categories. I have added textview and checkbox on recyclerview item. The problem is if I select one checkbox, it also selects multiple checkbox in the list. For example if I select 1st checkbox in the list it automatically selects every 10th checkbox in the list. Thanks

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    android:background="#FFF"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/categoryName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
            android:text="Category"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/categoryCount"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/categoryCount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:text="Count"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/categoryCheck"
            android:layout_width="28dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
            android:buttonTint="@color/red"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Adapter.java

```
public class CategorySelector extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategorySelector.ViewHolder> {

LayoutInflater inflater;
List<Category> categoryList;
List<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<>();

public CategorySelector(Context ctx, List<Category> categoryList){
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    this.categoryList = categoryList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_select, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.categoryName.setText(categoryList.get(position).getCategoryName());
    holder.categoryCount.setText(String.valueOf(categoryList.get(position).getCategoryCount()));
    holder.categoryCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                selectedItems.add(categoryList.get(position).getCategoryName());
            } else{
                selectedItems.remove(categoryList.get(position).getCategoryName());
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return categoryList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView categoryName;
    TextView categoryCount;
    CheckBox categoryCheck;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        categoryName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryName);
        categoryCount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryCount);
        categoryCheck = itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryCheck);
    }
}

public List<String> getSelectedItems(){
    return selectedItems;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your checkBox changeListener use instead of using position use :

> ```
>     holder.getAdapterPosition()
> ```

then set your checkBox select with your item :

```
holder.categoryCheck.setChecked(//set your boolean is selected before);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but there is no problem on adding correct data to list, only problem in UI that I if check the 1st check box it selects every 10th checkbox, If I uncheck any one of them then all the 10th checkbox unchecks automatically.